# ESP BLE MESH - Can a node notify it getting provisioned a peer node of the same mesh network?

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, provisioning

Is there any way to notify for a node to notify other nodes immediately after getting provisioned? I am using ESP32 as the microcontroller and using the ESP BLE MESH SDK provided by Espressif.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways to do this. One straightforward way i can think of would be to make use of the ESP_BLE_MESH_NODE_PROV_COMPLETE_EVT which will trigger as a callback event after provisioning is complete. When the event triggers, you can send a message to all other nodes (0xFFFF which is to all nodes' address as per ESP BLE MESH SDK) to "notify" them. The API for sending message on application layer would be something like esp_ble_mesh_server_model_send_msg() for example. You can refer to https://espressif-docs.readthedocs-hosted.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/api-reference/bluetooth/esp-ble-mesh.html for more details